# order of transfer all files under a directory by rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

If transfer all files under a directory by rsync, what is the order that rsync determines to transfer the files one by one?

At first it looked like rsync transfers files in alphabetical order, but later I found rsync skipped some files in the first sweep through the alphabetic order, and then went back to transfer files that were skipped in the first time and this time still in alphabetic order.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that it transfers the files in the order that they are listed in the *directory entry* for the directory that they are in.  This is generally the order that the files were added to the directory, but if a files is deleted, its spot will be used by the next file added to the directory.  You can see this by using `ls -f`. If you are really interested in the gory details, try `man readdir` on Linux or `man dir` on OS X.

Comment: I don't have a getdents on osx, what does it show?

Comment: @wizard I've updated my answer to point to OS X info as well.

Comment: [ls -U](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/ls.1.php) (listing files in directory order) can be useful too for watching rsync's progress.

Answer (score 2):

It looks alphabetical order when I tested.  Besides, according to [man > SORTED TRANSFER ORDER](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html), some sorting is executed as:

> Rsync always sorts the specified filenames into its internal transfer list...

Probably, we can say that at least rsync does not follow just directory entry order.

Comment: I don't think it's simply alphabetical for me (not sure), but I can confirm that one large directory in my home directory is always last even though `ls -f` and `ls -U` puts it near the beginning.  This was probably just a change since the other answer, since it's been almost 12 years.